# displaying radio button values on different textbox

Tags: php, jquery, combobox

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script>
    google.load("jquery", "1.4.0");
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() 
    {    
        $('input[type=button]').click(function () 
        {
            var txtbox = $('#buttoncheck1').attr('name');
            var var_name = $("input[name='radio1']:checked").val();
            $('#btn_get').val(var_name);
        });
    });
</script>
<html>
    <body>
    <?php 

        for($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++)
        {
            echo "

            <div id = 'div1' name = 'div1'>
            <input type='radio' value='Blue' name='radio1'>Blue</input>
            <input type='radio' value='White' name='radio1'>White</input>
            <input type='radio' value='Red' name='radio1'>Red</input>
            <input id='buttoncheck1' type='button' name='btn' value='Click'></input>
            <br />
            <input type='text' id='btn_get' name='get_btn_value'></input>
            </div>

            ";
        }


    ?>        
    </body>
</html>
```

I can clearly get all the values of the radio buttons in this code but the only problem I've been solving for almost 3 days is that I cant display the value on other textbox. all the values from all the radio button groups are only displayed on the first textbox produced by the loop. please help me . thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`id` values should always be unique.  You can change your duplicated `id`s to `class` values and do the following:

```
$('input[type=button]').click(function () 
{
    var $parent = $(this).parent();
    var var_name = $parent.find("input[name='radio1']:checked").val();
    $parent.find('.btn_get').val(var_name);
});
```